# How do I recover my firefox tabs?

Tags: firefox, tabs

I reinstalled my Ubuntu, I saved my profile that resides in `~/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE`. I assumed it would restore my tabs after I copied the profile back.

History and such is available, but no tabs including pinned tabs.

I also had Firefox Sync, but that does the same, history and such back, but no tabs!

In the settings I have and had tabs enabled?

Comment: you may find this helpful: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1028115